# X Y Positioning after an Item Selected in Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery, positioning, offset

I have a vertical "Refine Search" results bar on the left-hand side of a page.  Because this menu can be long, I am wanting an "Update Results" button to appear to the left after a selection is made somewhere on that menu so that the user can quickly press the button after their changes have been refined.  Everything works great except when you make a selection from a drop-down menu.  For some reason, the button always goes back up to the top of the page after a selection has been made from the drop down menu.  It only does this for drop down menus.

I am using the following jquery code:

```
$(".topLeftNavBarInner").click(function(e){
        var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
        var relX = parentOffset.left-140;
        var relY = e.pageY-15;
        $(".FloatingUpdateSearchResultsDiv").show();
        $(".FloatingUpdateSearchResultsDiv").css({position:"absolute",left:relX,top:relY});
});
```

You can see what I am talking about by testing it here.  Click "Magnification Type" on the "Refine Search" menu on the left of the page:
http://www.scopemonster.com/search777.php?Cat=91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely due to the calculation of $(this).offset() is based on the position of the "option" element and not the parent "select" that I'm guessing you're wanting to target.

<strike>Consider this approach:</strike>

```
var parentOffset;
if($(this).is('option'))
    parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
else
    parentOffset = $(this).offset();
```

**UPDATE**:

```
$(".topLeftNavBarInner").click(function(e){
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
    var relX = parentOffset.left-140;
    var relY;
    if(e.target.nodeName=='OPTION') {
        var selectOffset = $(e.target).parent().offset();
        relY = selectOffset.top;
    }
    else
        relY = e.pageY-15;
    $(".FloatingUpdateSearchResultsDiv").show();
    $(".FloatingUpdateSearchResultsDiv").css({position:"absolute",left:relX,top:relY});
});
```

You may still choose to manipulate the "relY" value in the case of an OPTION being the source of the click but this should keep the floating DIV in the area you want.

Comment: I tried adjusting the code as mentioned, but still getting the same results.

Comment: I've also just tried doing it this way on line 2 with the same results: 'var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();`

Comment: Ahh, nevermind - I wasn't tracking the .topLeftNavBarInner DIV was the entire Refine Search box. Sorry, let me look closer...

Comment: It's still working the same, even with the UPDATE code.

Comment: Stevangelista, it looks like your code works in Google Chrome.  Not working in IE for some reason.  However, you need to change "OPTION" to "SELECT" and it works in Chrome.

Comment: That's odd - I tested in Firefox & it worked as expected. RE: the nodeName you test for, it depends on which click event you're trying to catch: "OPTION" will catch the selection of an item in the dropdown while "SELECT" will catch the user opening the dropdown. Hopefully these help point you in the right direction; I gather the goal is to capture the location of the SELECT, not the mouse cursor itself, when the user clicks a choice from the dropdown and then place the floating DIV there.

Comment: Got it to work in all major browsers, just have to change e.target.nodeName=='OPTION' to e.target.nodeName=='OPTION' || e.target.nodeName=='SELECT'  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent - sorry for the roundabout path; it's my first day on SO

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help!  I would have never found answer without it!